# Using Laravel controller to show same items on different pages

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I've created a web application using laravel. The application is a combination of a blog website and an e-commerce store. On the index page, I've made a blog controller and products controller which display 3 items for the blog and 4 items for the products respectively on the index page. Now, I've also created a separate page for the blog where all the blogs (3 blogs) in the website will be displayed and a separate page for the products where all the products will be displayed (5 books).

I wanted to ask if there is a way in which I could display a different number of products on both the index page and the products page using the same controller (products controller.). By either using loops or something else.

This is the code that I've used to display the products on the index page which displays 4 products on the index page. If you have any resources which can help me, please link them.

```
Product::factory()->count(4)->create();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the DRY methodology while creating any kind of code.

Create a function that can be re-use.

```
public function index(){
    $blogs = $this->getBlogs(3); //Parameterized getblogs() which return only 3 blogs
    $products = $this->getProducts(4); //Parameterized getProducts() which return only 4 products
    return view('index', compact('blogs', 'products'))
}


public function product_view() {
    $products = $this->getProducts(9);
    return view('product', compact('blogs', 'products'))
}

//this function required one integer value which be will use to fetch that number of products
//If this kind of function will be used by another class file then you should define this function in any service container or as a helper or In the model itself. so this function can be used by other classes as well.
public function getProducts(int $limit) {
    return Product::take($limit)->get()
}
```